# Cannot Login into a Page with Selenium but manual Login Works

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to Automate Login in my C# application. However, the Page I am trying to Log into, has some kind of captcha or bot detection technique which results in "Incorrect Credentials" even when those credentials are correct. Manual Login works with the same credentials.

Things that I have tried:

1. Set an user agent and user data directory for chromeOptions.
2. Added ExcludedArguments of "enable-automation" which disables the infobar of "Chrome is being controlled by automated software"
3. Tried Chrome, FireFox and IE in Headless Mode.
4. Added random waits (Thread Sleeps) in the login code so that I am not Logging in too fast.
5. Tried Submit instead of click
6. Tried Chrome Incognito Mode.

P.S It does show a different login interface when automation is attached to chrome which has a user logged in (chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried chrome option useAutomationExtension and exclude switch

Python Code would be something like --

```
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",['enable-automation'])
opt.add_experimental_option("'useAutomationExtension',False)
```